# What are the odds of a straight and three three-of-a-kinds in poker?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, poker

How do you calculate the odds of this happening in poker?

> There are 4 players. Each of them had a pair each of the cards K,Q,A,10 in pre flop itself. The cards on the table are 5, 10, A, Q J So the winner had a straight. But the other three players each had a three of a kind. what are the odds of this happening, and how can we calculate that?

Hands of players:
$$ 1:\fbox{$\color{red} {\substack{K\\\heartsuit}}$},\fbox{$\substack{K\\\spadesuit}$}.\quad 
2:
\fbox{$\color{black} {\substack{Q\\\spadesuit}}$},\fbox{$\color{red} {\substack{Q\\\heartsuit}}$}.\quad
3: \fbox{$\color{red} {\substack{10\\\heartsuit}}$},\fbox{$\substack{10\\\spadesuit}$}. \quad
4:\fbox{$\color{black} {\substack{A\\\spadesuit}}$},\fbox{$\color{blue}{\substack{A\\\diamondsuit}}$}.$$
Cards on the table:
$$ \fbox{$\color{red} {\substack{5\\\heartsuit}}$}, \fbox{$\color{green} {\substack{10\\\clubsuit}}$}, \fbox{$\color{red} {\substack{A\\\heartsuit}}$},\fbox{$\color{blue} {\substack{Q\\\diamondsuit}}$},\fbox{$\color{blue} {\substack{J\\\diamondsuit}}$}.$$

[the picture for reference:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HG3l.jpg)

[image]

Comment: It's a very tiny probability.

Comment: @Darkwillow Has this actually occured in a real game in the internet ?

Comment: I tried to make a good title, but if it is not what you meant, please edit it.

Comment: @Peter I got it as a whatsapp forward saying it really happened. Im not sure if it did. Was curious when I found it.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you so much for the edit. I cudnt hv done any better :)

Comment: Curious, but considering that all players were all in (except the one with the most money) , makes it plausible that it actually happened.

Comment: @Peter I just confirmed....apparently it really did happen...